# Serializing a mixed value xml element, gives error

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I get this error 
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

> Unexpected type 'A' with data contract name 'A:
>   http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' . If you are using
>   DataContractSerializer, try using DataContractResolver or add types
>   not known statically to the list of known types (for example, using
>   the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of
>   known types passed to DataContractSerializer).

when serializing an object with a property that can be 2 types A or B.

xsd.exe generated the object like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class Doc
{    
    [XmlElement("A", typeof(A))]
    [XmlElement("B", typeof(B))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute(typeof(string))]
    public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

Type A and B are defined too, just normal classes with 1 property.

and I initialize the object like this

```
Doc d = new Doc();

var i = new A
{
    Id = 1,
};

doc.Item = i;
```

which compiles fine, but when it tries to serialize it throws the error mentioned above

Comment: And can you please include the serializer code?

Comment: You are marking your class with [`XmlSerializer` attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but your exception was generated by [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a completely different serializer that uses different attributes.  You need to use [`svcutil.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate classes for it.

Comment: This is an mvc project, do I still have to use scvutil.exe ? I only have an xsd

Comment: I think if you show us the serializer code the picture will be a lot clearer

Comment: How do I change the Asp.Net MVC to user xmlserializer instead of the datacontractseriallizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need a common base class where you can specify known types:

```
[KnownType(typeof(A))]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
public class AorB
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class A : AorB
{
}

public class B : AorB
{
}
```

then in doc class:

```
public partial class Doc
{    
    public AorB Item { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using DataContractSerializer, you can pass an IEnumerable of known types into the constructor:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typof(Doc), new[] { typeof(A), typeof(B) });
```

Comment: Brilliant, the AorB solution works !, but it comes out like this 
<Item i:type="A"> instead of <A>

Comment: OK, I'll accept your answer, just in case someone else runs into the issue, .Net MVC uses Data Contact for serializing XML by default and to change it you can se
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;

in the golbal.asax